# Why isn't my sound in stereo?

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio

I recently pumped new live into an old Packard bell Packard Bell Easynote TK85-GU-120 ([Specifications, in Dutch](https://tweakers.net/pricewatch/267550/packard-bell-easynote-tk85-gu-120-(zwart)/specificaties/)). It works fine, the audio driver seems to be working.

In the System Settings, all output devices are showing up and have sound profiles such as `Analog stereo output`, `Stereo HDMI` and `Digital surround HDMI`.

But I definitely only hear the left speaker making sound, the right speaker is silent. But it was fine on Windows…

The sound card is a Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 05)

Comment: Did you check System Settings -> Sound -> Profile? Is the Balance slider in the middle?

Comment: in pulse audio it is... or pauvcontrol.

Comment: Are you sure the Balanced slider is in the middle/The left and right sliders are both opened equally?

Comment: Look for yourself ;) 
https://ibb.co/hHJsDJ (img BB)

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of the Advanced section as well?

Comment: sure! https://ibb.co/fQNind (img BB)

Comment: Everything seems okay over there. Is there one particular application that doesn't play stereo, or does every application plays mono sound?

Comment: Well It happens to system sounds as well

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm sorry, I do not see a solution at the moment. You could always try the [Ubuntu forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/)